# Check for inheritance at runtime having only one of the types and void*

Tags: c++

I need a way to check at runtime whether a type is related by inheritance to a type of an anonymous object, void pointer for my purpose.

Let's say I have two types:

```
class Base
{
public:
  virtual ~Base();
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
  ~Derived();
};

Base *base = new Derived();
Derived *derived = new Derived();
```

I need to implement the following function:

```
template <typename T>
T *isRelated(void *obj, void *tag)
{
  //If T is related to obj's real type (established based on tag value)
  //    return reinterpret_cast<T*>(obj);
  //else
  //    return nullptr;
}
```

Currently, I can check whether obj *is* the same type as T by storing any one value in typetag (determined at compile-time and returned as a value), and comparing for equality.

In other words, current typetag implementation is similar to this:

```
template <typename T>
void *getTypeTag();

template <>
void *getTypeTag<Base>()
{
  return 1;
}

template <>
void *getTypeTag<Derived>()
{
  return 2;
}
```

What can I store in typetag to also check for inheritance relationship?

I'm seeking a scalable solution, since there will be many classes with frequent inheritance relationships.

Edit/Clarification:

- I'm working with a 3rd party API that will only give me void
  pointers, therefore overloading isRelated based on typed obj is not
  possible
- Dynamic casts aren't possible because they don't work between T and void*

Comment: So what's wrong with [`dynamic_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast)?

Comment: Also, doing something like this on a large scale is, IMO, a sign of a bad design.

Comment: Can't use dynamic_cast because I only have 1 type, and a void* - dynamic cast doesn't work like that. If you don't have a solution (or knowledge outside of the function scope and the fact that I need to scale - meaning I don't want to hardcode relationships) - I'd like to kindly ask that you please refrain from design quality analysis.
Edit: for clarity, I am interacting with unchangeable 3rd party API

Comment: This sounds like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Casting `void*` to `T*` based on `void*`s whose values can be `1` or `2` does not sound right at all.

Comment: "`dynamic_cast` doesn't work like" - You should doubt your pre-conceptions. `dynamic_cast` inter-operates with `void*` is several ways. So long as the types are polymorphic.

Comment: @RSahu, thanks, I'll clarify: 1 and 2 are contrived examples that can be used for comparison, and are void *typetags, not void *obj. Typetags are not cast to T*, obj are. typetags can store whatever value I want - 1 and 2 are just examples. I have constraints that are unchangeable, XY or not I need a solution within my parameters.

Comment: @StoryTeller - again, no. I'm casting FROM void*, not TO void*, dynamic_cast doesn't work like that. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast, Explanation #4.

Comment: About the only meaningful thing you can do with a `void*` is to cast it back to its original type (not counting trivial things like comparing for equality or printing). If you can do that, fine, do that. If you can't, tough luck.

Comment: Point 4 in the explanation is about casting ***to*** `void*`.

Comment: @StoryTeller "Several ways"? There's basically only one way: a `dynamic_cast` to _cv_ `void*` gives the address of the most-derived object.

Comment: @n.m. thank you, in this case I also get a void* typetag - which I can cast to any known polymorphic type of my choosing, and use it as 'description' of my type. But I cannot declare virtual template methods to do further checks down the hierarchy, I'm hoping for some creative suggestions

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude exactly, and I'm casting *from* void*, I'm afraid StoryTeller misread the question

Comment: Well then, there is a world beyond standard C++ if you are truly desperate. A compiler's ABI bindings may offer you the exact things you want. For instance [GCC](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/libsupc%2B%2B/dyncast.cc).

Comment: Your "typetag" seems to be a poor-man's version of `std::type_info`.  Basically, no, this is not possible because as n.m. pointed out, there are very few valid things to do with a `void*` pointer.  Using `void*` in C++, except where some C interface absolutely requires it, is almost always a design mistake.

Comment: @StoryTeller oof, I'm afraid that's perhaps more creative than I'm willing to get with this :) Thank you, I will study it in case I get desperate

Comment: @aschepler that's one line of thought to this, but typetag can be my own base type of some sorts (let's call it FooTag) - which allows more creativity than std::type_info. Maybe I can dynamic cast it down to a specialized version, like FooTagType<T>, maybe I can take advantage of cast overloads to support some kind of hierarchy enforcements or other functionality. I'm hoping to get some creative answers, rather than a matter of fact no

Comment: Posted code doesn't seem to be a good representative of your real situation. You are showing a function template `isRelated` that knows about two `void` pointers and a single type `T`. The only thing it can do is to cast these two pointers to the same type (either `T` or some related type). In order to cast the two object to two different types it must know about two different types.

Comment: @n.m. thanks for your criticism, the question is an entirely valid representation of my situation; If I may be honest, I am much better informed about the scope and constraints of the code I'm working on, and the problem is clearly stated in the question. Having said that, I provided a working answer to the question. Please let me know if you can do better - I'd love a more elegant solution if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I initially edited my first answer, but it ended up being too long.

Here's a second solution, this one does not rely on undefined behavior (or shouldn't, unless I've made a mistake).

This solution also has limitations, but does not rely on undefined behavior.

**Limitations**:

- Multiple inheritance is unsupported
- Only upcasting is supported (downcast support would be fairly easy to
  add)

The implementation may look a bit odd at first glance, but is relatively straightforward. Many things can be done differently, some early-outs could be added, better organization, different structuring, etc.

**Brief description**:

Base TypeTag implements a virtual method, which takes our desired Type's typeid, and carries it all the way back to the top-level TypeTagSpec. From there, we begin a recursive descent through the TypeTagCastPropagator, performing a clean cast each step down, until we find and return the desired type object.

If the desired type is not found in the inheritance chain, then nullptr is returned.

If the desired type is not even specialized under TypeTag, then nullptr is returned.

Base types, the virtual methods are used to carry the desired typeid back to the original type that was allocated:

```
// This is what gets stored in void *tag
struct TypeTag
{
  virtual ~TypeTag(){}
  virtual void *isRelated(void *obj,
                          const std::type_info &type_desired) const = 0;
};

// Unspecialized implementation, waiting to be specialized
template <typename T>
struct TypeTagSpec : TypeTag
{
  virtual ~TypeTagSpec(){}
  virtual void *isRelated(void *obj,
                          const std::type_info &type_desired) const override = 0;
};
```

Now, TypeTagCastPropagator implementation - this performs a recursive descent down the inheritance hierarchy. It has two possible scenarios:
 - Reaching the final base type
 - Reaching an intermediate base type

```
template <typename D>
struct TypeTagCastPropagator
{
  // Non-propagating version, base -> base (no further casts possible)
  template <typename B,
            typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<B, D>::value>::type* = nullptr>
  void *castDown(const TypeTagSpec<D> *self, void *obj,
                 const std::type_info &desired) const
  {
    D *derived = reinterpret_cast<D*>(obj);
    if(typeid(D) == desired)
      return obj;
    return nullptr;
  }

  // Propagating version, derived -> base
  template <typename B,
            typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<B, D>::value &&
                                    !std::is_same<B, D>::value>::type* = nullptr>
  void *castDown(const TypeTagSpec<D> *self, void *obj,
                 const std::type_info &desired) const
  {
    // Check to see if we are dealing with the desired type
    D *derived = reinterpret_cast<D*>(obj);
    if(typeid(D) == desired)
      return obj;

    // Attempt to upcast
    B *base = dynamic_cast<B*>(derived);
    const auto *tag = dynamic_cast<const TypeTagSpec<B>*>(self);
    if(base && tag)
      return tag->propagator.template castDown<B>(tag, base, desired);
    return nullptr;
  }
};
```

Lastly, the tag specializations. These are sufficiently generic that they can be placed in a macro and specialized for any type.

```
template <>
struct TypeTagSpec<Base> : TypeTag
{
  TypeTagCastPropagator<Base> propagator;
  virtual void *isRelated(void *obj,
                          const std::type_info &desired) const override
  {
    // Base->Base indicates that there are no more meaningful inheritance checks to make
    return propagator.castDown<Base>(this, obj, desired);
  }
};

template <>
struct TypeTagSpec<Derived> : TypeTagSpec<Base>
{
  TypeTagCastPropagator<Derived> propagator;
  virtual void *isRelated(void *obj,
                          const std::type_info &desired) const override
  {
    return propagator.castDown<Base>(this, obj, desired);
  }
};
```

And the final function:

```
template <typename T>
T *isRelated(void *obj, void *tag)
{
  const TypeTag *typetag = reinterpret_cast<TypeTag*>(tag);
  void *result = typetag->isRelated(obj, typeid(T));
  if(result)
    return reinterpret_cast<T*>(obj);
  return nullptr;
}
```

This passes original tests at the bottom of the first answer, as well as undisclosed additional ones.

Answer (score 9):

I added another answer, which does not rely on undefined behavior.

---

WARNING: The answer below depends on undefined behavior

C++14 Standard:
http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf

> Chapter 10, Section 5:
>
> The order in which the base class subobjects are allocated in the most
>   derived object (1.8) is unspecified

By this logic, `reinterpret_cast` in my answer will rely on undefined behavior to work. Additionally, considering the `void*` is being cast - there appears to be no way to safely cast it to a base class without knowing the original type.

---

Came up with one possible solution, works quite well - but it is restrictive in the following ways:

- I have to specialize TypeTagSpec with inheritance pattern that reflects the original type's inheritance
- Validation happens on the type layer, rather than object pointer layer (this is clarified in the last paragraph)

Considering the contrived example classes Base and Derived, let's assume we'll add one more class 'Unrelated':

```
// Some class which is not related to our inheritance check, for testing later
class Unrelated
{
public:
    virtual ~Unrelated(){}
};
```

Now, subsequent specialized TypeTagSpec structs will be instantiated and passed to some API as void *tag:

```
// This is the base class, and we will initially cast all void *tag objects to this type
struct TypeTag
{
  virtual ~TypeTag(){}
};

// Unspecialized template derives from TypeTag, to give us a way 'up' the inheritance
template <typename T>
struct TypeTagSpec : TypeTag
{
  virtual ~TypeTagSpec(){}
};

// Specialized testing typetag for Unrelated type, used for testing
template <>
struct TypeTagSpec<Unrelated> : TypeTag
{
  virtual ~TypeTagSpec(){}
};

// Specialized Base typetag, nothing special
template <>
struct TypeTagSpec<Base> : TypeTag
{
  virtual ~TypeTagSpec(){}
};

// Magic here - specialized tagtype for Derived actually inherits from Base typetag, giving a clear inheritance line
template <>
struct TypeTagSpec<Derived> : TypeTagSpec<Base>
{
  virtual ~TypeTagSpec(){}
};
```

This leaves us with the code:

```
// The solution
template <typename T>
T *isRelated(void *obj, void *tag)
{
  const TypeTag *typetag = reinterpret_cast<TypeTag*>(tag);
  if(dynamic_cast<const TypeTagSpec<T>*>(typetag))
    return reinterpret_cast<T*>(obj);
  return nullptr;
}

TEST(TypeTag, Inheritance)
{
  Derived *derived = new Derived();
  TypeTag *typetag = new TypeTagSpec<Derived>();

  // Test begins here
  void *obj = derived;
  void *tag = typetag;

  EXPECT_EQ(isRelated<Base>(obj, tag), derived);
  EXPECT_EQ(isRelated<Derived>(obj, tag), derived);
  EXPECT_EQ(isRelated<Unrelated>(obj, tag), nullptr);
  // Test ends here

  delete derived;
  delete typetag;
}
```

It's important to note that the problem is to find whether the type is *related*, therefore this test will pass:

```
 auto *base = new Base();
 auto *tag = new TypeTagSpec<Base>();
 EXPECT_EQ(isRelated<Derived>(base, tag), base);
```

In this test, isRelated will still return a pointer to base; in practice this pointer may not always be valid/usable, depends on what classes are being casted. Since my use case involves upcasting type-layer relationship checks, I don't care about this object validity nuance - and the relationship is still technically valid from the type perspective (not object perspective).

Side note:
Whoever downvoted my original question within 5 minutes of asking it is petty, and happier downvoting than being helpful.

Comment: Your solution has **undefined behaviour** because reinterpret-casting `Derived*` to `Base*` is a no-no.

Comment: [Here's an illustration](https://ideone.com/hKD3Sm) and before saying that you don't have multiple inheritance and therefore it's OK try to  read the standard and find one behaviour that is well defined in a single inheritance situation and undefined for multiple inheritance. Undefined is undefined. If it happens to produce expected results in your particular case with your particular implementation, it doesn't make it less undefined.

Comment: @n.m.First of all, the non standard-layout you suggested in your “illustration” is called **diamond inheritance**, and you will not find it in my code. Furthermore, in your “illustration”, you couldn’t even *implicitly* cast `Mixed*` to `Base*` without a static or dynamic cast to either `Derived1*` or `Derived2*` - that is in order to resolve the ambiguity.

Comment: @n.m. Second of all, reinterpret_cast’ing `Derived*` to `Base*` **is in fact defined behavior** (to be clear - Base* to Derived* is undefined). If you’re making such bold claims, you should cite the standard yourself. Here’s my [supporting document](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast): - section: 6 (pay attention to type aliasing) - clarified under Notes as “AliasedType is a (possibly cv-qualified) base class of DynamicType.". Furthermore, **it gives an example of what is OK** (Derived* to Base*), literally search for "auto p1 = reinterpret_cast<S*>(&s1);”

Comment: @n.m The link goes as far as even showing a diamond inheritance example as **not ok**, obviously. “Illustrating” that for me was *very* unnecessary. In conclusion, since I intend to upcast only, and I will not have diamond inheritance problems, this answer appears OK so far (though I’m yet to refine it).

Comment: Let's try again. Reinterpret-casting `Derived*` to `Base*` is UB. Reinterpret-casting `Base*` to `Derived*` is also UB. The example only illustrates that, it doesn't prove anything. The proof is in the standard. Your quote has **nothing to do** with reinterpret cast and doesn't support your claim. Single inheritance may appear to work as expected but it is no less UB than the multiple inheritance case (not necessarily diamond BTW, it will also break without the diamond). If you are willing to work with UB, more power to you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182127/discussion-between-kaa-and-n-m).